# Uncaught ReferenceError: target is not defined (SmoothScroll)

Tags: javascript

My JS code for smooth scrolling is returning the error that the target is not defined, I'm not 100% sure what this means so I'm unable to fix the error myself.

Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: target is not defined

What do I need to define for this to work correctly?

Working example: http://oxfordlocks.co.uk/Explore/beast.html

JS:

```
  function init(){
    new SmoothScroll(document,30,24)
  }

  function SmoothScroll(body, speed, smooth) {
    if (target === document)
      target = (document.scrollingElement 
                || document.documentElement 
                || document.body.parentNode 
                || document.body) // cross browser support for document scrolling

    var moving = false
    var pos = target.scrollTop
    var frame = target === document.body 
                && document.documentElement 
                ? document.documentElement 
                : target // safari is the new IE

    target.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrolled, { passive: false })
    target.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrolled, { passive: false })

    function scrolled(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // disable default scrolling

      var delta = normalizeWheelDelta(e)

      pos += -delta * speed
      pos = Math.max(0, Math.min(pos, target.scrollHeight - frame.clientHeight)) // limit scrolling

      if (!moving) update()
    }

    function normalizeWheelDelta(e){
      if(e.detail){
        if(e.wheelDelta)
          return e.wheelDelta/e.detail/40 * (e.detail>0 ? 1 : -1) // Opera
        else
          return -e.detail/3 // Firefox
      }else
        return e.wheelDelta/120 // IE,Safari,Chrome
    }

    function update() {
      moving = true

      var delta = (pos - target.scrollTop) / smooth

      target.scrollTop += delta

      if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.5)
        requestFrame(update)
      else
        moving = false
    }

    var requestFrame = function() { // requestAnimationFrame cross browser
      return (
        window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(func) {
          window.setTimeout(func, 1000 / 50);
        }
      );
    }()
  }
```

Comment: You are using variable with name `target` like this `if (target === document)`
but I couldn't see where you declare and initiate this variable

Comment: In strict mode all variables must be explicitly declared. I presume the parameter `body` should be named `target` (but I am guessing). Another possibility: usually `target` is retrieved from the event, so you might be missing a parameter for the event (from which you could then retrieve the `target`).

Comment: you don't have any declared variable with name `target` in your scope so your scopreManager couldn't find this variable in your lexical scope

Comment: looks like it should be `function SmoothScroll(target, speed, smooth)`